# Trying to write cross-browser event disabling js function. What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to write my own function to block events.

Here is what I have:

```
function disableEvent (element, event, useCapture) {
    function preventer (event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        event.preventDefault() ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);        
        event.stopPropagation() ? event.stopPropagation() : (event.cancelBubble = true);        
    }    
    if (typeof useCapture == 'undefined') useCapture = false;
        if (element.addEventListener)
            element.addEventListener(event.toLowerCase().substr(2), preventer, useCapture)
        else if (element.attachEvent) {
            var result = element.attachEvent(event,preventer);
            return result;
        }
        else {
            alert("Try to change or update your browser")
        }                        
}
```

But it does not work on IE browser. It shows me an error on 4th line. Appreciate your help with this task.

Comment: You're calling `preventDefault()` (with parentheses) instead of checking if it's present... Also, I hope that alert isn't in the production version ;-)

Comment: @Cameron - post that as an answer.  I was about to until I saw your comment... It'd feel like cheating.  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to test if function exists, you write:

```
event.stopPropagation() ? event.stopPropagation() : (event.cancelBubble = true);
```

Let us analyse this. `event.stopPropagation()` is a call to `event.stopPropagation` without parameters, it doesn't return anything, that means `undefined`. So you'll face one problem:
if `stopPropagation` doesn't exist, you are still calling it. It produces an error, that's what happens in your case.

To avoid this problem, you have to check weither the function exists or not:

```
event.stopPropagation ? event.stopPropagation() : (even.cancelBubble = true);
```

It should work properly. Same thing with `preventDefault`.